# how to shout out, scream, cry out or yell at in Alexa Skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

I would like to create a skill to yell at someone, but i can not find any reference in SSML to yell or scream.

Is it even possible ?

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the result?

Comment: I tried the "emphasis" tag, please se more in: https://developer.amazon.com/es-ES/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#emphasis

Answer (score 0):

Use audio file for doing that. You can record or download from the internet and use it in ssml audio format. You just have to put your audio url as done in code below.

```
<speak>
<audio src="soundbank://soundlibrary/transportation/amzn_sfx_car_accelerate_01"/> 
</speak>
```

Comment: Thanks you, yes I am aware of this solution, but my question is if it could be done directly in SSML with some tag. The problem with recording is to translate the audio in multiples languages.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no yelling supported. The closest expression you could achieve with SSML is using the custom tag for emotions:

<amazon:emotion name="excited" intensity="medium">Hey, I'm so excited!</amazon:emotion>

The support of emotions varies across locales and I suggest to keep an eye on the dev blog posts to keep track of new possibilities:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2020/11/alexa-speaking-styles-emotions-now-available-additional-languages